# Python : Function to get the next character of a giving position of strings of a dataframe

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I want to get the next character giving a position of a another character of a string in a dataframe. If we have browsed every character of a string I should go to the next line.

And to do so I have written the function bellow.

```
def get_char(df, y, z):
    if z < len(df[0][y])-1: 
        return df[0][y][z+1]
    elif z == len(df[0][y])-1:
        if y < len(df[0])-1:
            return df[0][y+1][0]
```

so for the dataframe :

```
ar = np.array(["aba", "bcb", "zab"])
df = pd.DataFrame(ar)
```

if I

```
print get_char(df, 1, 2)
```

gives me `z`

and

```
print get_char(df, 2, 2)
```

should return nothing , in my function it returns `None`

I am pretty sure that I can do it with a much easier way.

My dataframe will have only one column.

Comment: "Any help" is not a question!

Comment: You can simplify by removing the `return` statements with no value - Python functions return None by default at the end.  But this post is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you @JohnZwinck I didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ar = np.array(["aba", "bcb", "zab"])
df = pd.DataFrame(ar)

def get_char(df, y, z):
    a = ''.join(df.iloc[y:y+2,0])
    try:
        return a[z+1]
    except:
        return None

print(get_char(df, 1, 2))
# z
print(get_char(df, 2, 2))
# None
```